# Google Chart (inverse Y axis)

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I want to make a graph with Google Charts, but the problem is that I want to inverse the Y axis values (descending) and so that the points are put correspondingly. Current graph:

[image]

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=1:|02-21|02-22|02-23|02-25|02-26|02-27|03-01|03-02|03-03|03-05|03-06&chxp=1,0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100&chxr=0,3300000,3800000&chxs=0,676767,11,1,lt,676767|1,676767,11,0,l,676767&chxt=y,x&chs=580x260&cht=lc&chco=3D7930&chds=3300000,3800000&chd=t:3468012,3329144,3464622,3466918,3344139,3347158,3455670,3455670,3458259,3458259,3467341,3467341,3529001,3533528,3541234,3701639&chdlp=l&chg=10,10,2,3&chls=2,4,0
```

Any ideas how to proceed?

Thanks,
Jonas

Answer (score 1):

Aha, I think I found a solution myself:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Docs/thread?tid=0053b10a131e8516&hl=en